# django many to many query

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to create an application that would help me store old music.
These are my models.

```
class ArtistGenre(models.Model):
    genre_name = models.CharField('Genre', max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.genre_name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('genre_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class ArtistTrait(models.Model):
    trait_name = models.CharField('Trait', max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.trait_name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('trait_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Artist(models.Model):
    stage_name = models.CharField('Stage Name', max_length=255)
    real_name = models.CharField('Birth Name', max_length=255, blank=True)
    artist_genre = models.ForeignKey(ArtistGenre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artist_trait = models.ManyToManyField(ArtistTrait)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stage_name 
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile_artist', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

My hang-up is properly querying the ArtistGenre and ArtistTrait models in order to create clickable links that would list all artists in a Genre or with a particular Trait.
Do I have to create Many To Many fields in the Trait and Genre models that link to the artists or is there a way for me to query the it currently?
Thank You!

Comment: Did you try filtering Artist based on artist_genre and artist_trait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    stage_name = models.CharField('Stage Name', max_length=255)
    real_name = models.CharField('Birth Name', max_length=255, blank=True)
    artist_genre = models.ForeignKey(ArtistGenre, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='artists')
    artist_trait = models.ManyToManyField(ArtistTrait, related_name='artists')
```

Now from a given genre or trait model, you'll be able to get all the artists because of the `related_name` attribute.

```
# Get all artists from the ArtistGenre - 
genre = ArtistGenre.objects.first()
artists = genre.artists.all()

# Get all artists from ArtistTrait
artists = ArtistTrait.artists.all()
```

Comment: Thank YOU!! I looked all over for this and somehow I didn't come across the related_name attribute. Appreciate it.